# What does a null relation on all real numbers look like?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I'm being asked to test for reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity, and antisymmetry on a null relation for all real numbers, i.e. $X=\mathbb{R}; R = \emptyset $. What would such a resulting set look like? Just an empty set?

Comment: **Hint:** Define an equivalence relation such that no elements of $X$ satisfy the relation.